# Is there a way to view a map overview of an android project in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flowchart

I am working on an open source project but it turns out to have a lot of files. It is really difficult to understand which activity starts which activity or fragment and there are loads of layout files. Is there an external tool or a built in way in android studio that can show a flowchart or map overview of a project, making it easier to understand the project?

Comment: If the open source project is maintained - ask if there is a architecture document or perhaps a mailing list thread which might fill in the background of the project.

Comment: thanks, found a glossary